# Cloned the Ruby on Rails repository but cannot install bundled gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have cloned the Rails repository to try to help close a few issues and, of course, chose to follow The Hard Way of the [Contributing to Ruby on Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html) guide. Everything went fine, cloned the repo, started tracking upstream and went on to install the bundled gems and run the tests. Right off the bat I got this:

```
$ bundle install
Updating git://github.com/rails/arel.git
Updating git://github.com/brynary/rack-test.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/jquery-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/wycats/thor.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders.git
Updating git://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/voloko/sdoc.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders (= 0.0.1) ruby', which is required  by gem 'rails (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.
```

After trudging a bit on Google I found out that the gem **activerecord-deprecated_finders** seems to not have been released on Rubygems yet, which would explain that last error. [Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) suggests that these kind of dependencies can be declared on the Gemfile and would override the gemspec definition, which the good folks that develop Rails have indeed done:

```
# rails/Gemfile
...
gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders', github: 'rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders', branch: 'master'
...
```

I have tried the suggestion of one of the commenters on Yehuda's post but it also didn't work:

```
# rails/Gemfile
...
@dependencies.delete_if{ |d| d.name == 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'  }
...
```

So, I'm a bit of at a loss as to why the `bundle install` didn't go work. I found a reference to that gem on `activerecord/activerecord.gemspec` and commenting out that solves the issue but that hardly seems like an acceptable solution. Does anyone know where I might have gone wrong? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p286 and Bundler 1.2.3.

**PS**: I saw plenty of info regarding this very gem while generating a new Rails 4.0.0.beta application, which is not what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Thanks!

Comment: Please give your Gemfile